# How to store huge numbers in PHP

Tags: php, variables, size, type-conversion

I need to convert a number from 36<sup>-th</sup> base into an integer. The original number length is about 10 characters which seem to be bigger then PHP's limits for integers.

In my case the original number looks like this: `9F02tq977`. When converted I get the following result `8.46332972237E+12`.

How can I store huge numbers in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since BC Math doesn't work with arbitrary base numbers, you could try using GMP functions if you have them available.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php

Otherwise you'll probably have to rewrite your algorithm and write your own arbitrary precision arithemtic implementation of the validation algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Use a math library like BC Math for big numbers :)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: You'll still have some work converting it to decimal, BC math does not work in other bases than of 10.